# Fastest way to turn a ring of unconnected vertices into an edgeloop?

Tags: modeling, mesh

Let's say I have these two rings and they even match in vertexcount.

[image]

Is there a tool I have overlooked that will bridge them properly into a nice and clean faceloop?

Turning each ring into an edgeloop is good enough, too.

Comment: If there is way to select rings separately then you can fill temporary ngon out of them, remove only face and use edges left after ngon. However this won't work for multiple rings. I think you didn't miss any gui tools, since ones for point clouds are required here (or scripting, or I bet Animation Nodes / Sverchok)

Comment: @MrZak I hate cool comment answers. I cannot properly upvote them.

Comment: Hah, but you can upvote comment :) But seriously I'm not going so far to post it since it's not that much of solution to what is shown on your screenshot (2 separate rings of faces). With my way it's like cumbersome selection with Circle select or stuff

Comment: @MrZak select, face, delete, select, face, delete, select, bridge is faster than what I knew, so it counts. In the end it's all about gathering an arsenal of possible combinations.

Comment: The way I see it, either the vertex indexes are sequentially ordered so they could easily be connected by a script, or this would require some sort of spacial analysis to determine which point is closer to another and connect it, and would still be prone to failure

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos While it wouldn't be fool proof, you'd just have to connect the closest verts until all have two edges. Not a death ray, but faster than right now. For open loops the rule would be a bit different. One could also use a threshold to limit edge length.

Comment: In addition to DFR's comment on indices and proximity, are they circles? Are the points on the rings equidistant (or close to) from each other?

Comment: @batFINGER No, these are ellipses, so the distances vary slightly. For now I use the F method which is quite handy until the suffering makes me code a little addon.

Comment: @batFINGER Too bad no one writes cool addon templates that are explicitly overdocumented. Copying stuff without really understanding the internals leads to future trouble.

Comment: Just read through the comments and realised you’d alsready discussed the method in my answer - doh! I guess the difficulty is in the selection.

Answer (score 3):

Select all the inner faces with Circle Select or Lasso tool. Press <kbd>F</kbd> to create a face, then <kbd>X</kbd> and Only Faces to remove the face and leave just the edges. Select the outer vertices and repeat <kbd>F</kbd><kbd>X</kbd>. You should now have two loops - simply select all and Bridge Edge Loops.

As an alternative to Bridge Edge Loops, select two adjacent pairs of vertices and remove the two edges between each and join opposite ones to make a ‘C’ shape that almost joins. Select all and Grid Fill. Select the vertices around the gap and <kbd>F</kbd> to create the face.

Animated gif showing the process :

[image: animated]

Comment: Why Grid Fill instead of Bridge Edge Loops?

Comment: @Haunt_House TBH I hadn’t thought of using Bridge Edge Loops originally and was thinking of a way of indicating which pair of vertices should form the ‘start’ of the chain. With Bridge you don’t have any control but using Grid Fill you can set a specific edge.

Answer (score 3):

**Bmesh approach**

1. Make a convex hull [`bmesh.ops.convex_hull(...)`](https://docs.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/bmesh.ops.html#bmesh.ops.convex_hull)
2. Remove all but the outer smallest 2 edges on each vert in hull.
3. Return to step 1 with interior verts until there are no more.

---

[image]
*Result of running script on concentric 64 vert circles.*

Test Script run in edit mode.

```
import bpy
import bmesh
context = bpy.context

ob = context.object
me = ob.data
bm = bmesh.from_edit_mesh(me)
verts = bm.verts[:]
while verts:
    ret = bmesh.ops.convex_hull(bm, input=verts)

    ringverts = [v for v in ret['geom'] if isinstance(v, bmesh.types.BMVert) 
            and len(v.link_edges) > 2]

    while ringverts:
        v = ringverts.pop()
        linkedges = v.link_edges[:]
        linkedges.sort(key=lambda e: e.calc_length())
        for e in linkedges[2:]:
            bm.edges.remove(e)
    verts = ret['geom_interior']
# bridge edge loops
bmesh.ops.bridge_loops(bm, edges=bm.edges)

bmesh.update_edit_mesh(me)
```

Comment: If Ah ain't knowwyn what the lines do Ah ain't cohpyn it. Ah wanna lern.

Answer (score 1):

- Select all <kbd>A</kbd> and fill with <kbd>F</kbd>
- Inset twice with <kbd>I</kbd> and delete vertices
- Select all and use the *relax* operator 2 or 3 times with <kbd>W</kbd> then <kbd>X</kbd>
- Scale the innermost edge loop toward the center
- Use the *Circle* operator from the Loop Tools add-on on each loop, one at a time by pressing  <kbd>W</kbd>><kbd>L</kbd>><kbd>C</kbd>

Example Gif:
[image]

Comment: I like the creativity of that one

Comment: @Haunt_House thanks. Not sure why the dv, I was looking for a solution that didn't require any tedious lasso/circle selection.

Comment: the downvote comes probably because it's a solution that destroys any shape there previously was which limits its use a bit.